# Loop to Store multiple pandas dataframe into a List

Tags: python

I'm a beginner python user and I am wondering if it is possible to store multiple `dataframes` that is generated from a loop, into a list.

Unfortunately, I do not have a reproducible example. What I am trying to do is to read in a directory of pdf files, make row 0 into the header, drop that row and store it into one `dataframe` within a list.

```
master_df= []
for i in range(1, len(pdffiles)):
    df = read_pdf(pdffiles[i])
    df.columns = df.iloc[0,] #get col names
    df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0)) #drop first row
    df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True, inplace = True)
    master_df = df
```

This is the code that I have but I am getting this error at `df.columns, reindex` and `replace`.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Update:

May I ask why the following code does not work? I'm trying to parse in a `continue` when the dataframe is not a None set.

```
master_df = []
for i in range(len(pdffiles)):
    df = read_pdf(pdffiles[i])
    if df is not None:
        continue
    df.columns = df.iloc[0,:] # get col names
    df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0)) # drop first row
    df = df.fillna('')
    master_df.append(df)
```

Comment: `master_df.append(df)` and print `df` before replace and make sure it is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to store data frames in a list:

```
master_df = []
for i in range(len(pdffiles)):
    df = read_pdf(pdffiles[i])
    df.columns = df.iloc[0,:] # get col names
    df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0)) # drop first row
    df = df.fillna('')
    master_df.append(df)
```

You can use `df.fillna()` to replace `NaN` values with `''`.

Comment: great work, thanks, will accept as correct answer (:

Comment: hey @Nathaniel, do you mind helping me with the `continue` statement? I have some df that belongs to the `None` type but using `continue` did not seem to work